# Attempt to cast instance to PersistenceCapable failed. Ensure that it's been enhanced

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I'm trying out OpenJPA 2.0.1 for the first time, and am getting:

```
79  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - The configuration property named "openjpa.Id" was not recognized and will be ignored, although the name closely matches a valid property called "openjpa.Id".
179  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.0.1
371  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary" (PostgreSQL 8.4.4 ,PostgreSQL Native Driver PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 801)).
<openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to cast instance "x.quality.QualityQuery@4c4b11e9" to PersistenceCapable failed.  Ensure that it has been enhanced.
FailedObject: x.quality.QualityQuery@4c4b11e9
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assertPersistenceCapable(BrokerImpl.java:4559)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2561)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2423)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1069)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:706)
    at ...
```

According to [the OpenJPA docs](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.0.1/apache-openjpa-2.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html#ref_guide_pc_enhance_runtime), I shouldn't have to do anything to get the basic enhancement at runtime:

> 2.5.  Omitting the OpenJPA enhancer
>
> OpenJPA does not require that the
> enhancer be run. If you do not run the
> enhancer, OpenJPA will fall back to
> one of several possible alternatives
> for state tracking, depending on the
> execution environment.
>
> Java 6 class
> retransformation:
>
> if you are running
> your application in a Java 6
> environment, OpenJPA will attempt to
> dynamically register a
> ClassTransformer that will redefine
> your persistent classes on the fly to
> track access to persistent data.
> Additionally, OpenJPA will create a
> subclass for each of your persistent
> classes. When you execute a query or
> traverse a relation, OpenJPA will
> return an instance of the subclass.
> This means that the instanceof
> operator will work as expected, but
> o.getClass() will return the subclass
> instead of the class that you wrote.
> You do not need to do anything at all
> to get this behavior. OpenJPA will
> automatically detect whether or not
> the execution environment is capable
> of Java 6 class retransformation.

Any clues why this isn't working?  Thanks much...

(Bonus points for why the openjpa.Id warning happens - I haven't set any such property...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, turns out that the answer was to pass in:

```
"openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" => RuntimeUnenhancedClassesModes.SUPPORTED
```

to the configuration map.  Why this is not documented more clearly, I'm not sure...

Comment: I highly recommend NOT using that property. Please read http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html for more info.

Comment: @Rick: right now I'm just playing around and I really don't want to have to add a build step between every compile / run cycle...

Comment: I'd suggest using the -javaagent.... If you're running in eclipse it's super easy to get going.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work.  Didn't print out any messages at all (I have DEBUG level enabled), and it complained that the classes were not enhanced.